# Avoid doing double calculations in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm working on a XSLT transformation. I'm fairly new to XSLT, and I'm having some trouble with it to put it mildly. I'm working on some input, and based on some calculations (checking intersections on polygons, which takes extensive amounts of time, since the data amount is huge), I want to add some elements to a collection.

At the end of the output I want to have an indicator stating whether or not that list contains elements - really simple, but still having trouble. I found out that it's not possible to access the preliminary generated data inside the transformation, since apparently only the input is available.

this is my input. Note that this input can be repeated several times, so the transformation iterates over all the "IterationResponses".

```
    <IterationResponse Iteration="0">
    <QueryResult>
        <Collection>
            <Element>
                <Name>City1</Name>
                <number>151</number>
                <Link>Link1</Link>
                <GMLData>[massive data amount]</GMLData>
            </Element>
            <Element>
                <Name>City1</Name>
                <number>151</number>
                <Link>Link2</Link>
                <GMLData>[massive data amount]</GMLData>
            </Element>
            <Element>
                <Name>City2</Name>
                <number>190</number>
                <Link>Link3</Link>
                <GMLData>[massive data amount]</GMLData>
            </Element>
            <Element>
                <Name>City3</Name>
                <number>163</number>
                <Link>Link4</Link>
                <GMLData>[massive data amount]</GMLData>
            </Element>
        </Collection>
    </QueryResult>
    <Selection>
        <cadastral>
            <cadastralPolygon>
                <Polygon>
                    <exterior>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <posList>[small amount of data]</posList>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </exterior>
                </Polygon>
            </cadastralPolygon>
        </cadastral>
    </Selection>
</IterationResponse>
```

And this is the transformation I currently have (simplified **alot** since the actual input, transformation and output is huge, but the issue remains)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                              xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                              xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
                              xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="var_bufferWidth" select="'-0.5'" />

        <QueryResult>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="count(//Error) >= 1">
                <!-- Error handling -->
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>      
                    <Overview>
                        <OverviewCollection>
                            <!--Iterate all iteration responses--> 
                            <xsl:for-each select="//IterationResponse">
                                <xsl:variable name="cadastralGML" select="Selection/cadastral/cadastralPolygon"/>
                                <xsl:for-each select=".//Element">
                                    <xsl:if test="func:Conflicts($cadastralGML, GMLData, $var_bufferWidth)">
                                        <OverviewElement>
                                            <Number>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="concat('0',Kommunenummer)"/>
                                            </Number>
                                            <Name>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
                                            </Name>
                                            <Reference>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="Link"/>
                                            </Reference>
                                        </OverviewElement>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        <OverviewCollection>
                        <OverviewIndicator>
                          <xsl:value-of select="count(/*//OverviewElement) > 0"/>
                        <OverviewIndicator>
                    </Overview>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </QueryResult>
</xsl:template>
```

This is my current output.

```
<Overview>
  <OverviewCollection>
    <OverviewElement>
      <Number>0151</Number>
      <Name>City1</Name>
      <Reference>Link1</Reference>
    </OverviewElement>
  </OverviewCollection>
  <OverviewIndicator>false</OverviewIndicator>
</Overview>
```

Instead of false i want it to be true, since the final collection is not empty. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks as if you posted the XSLT twice, instead of showing the result you get.

Comment: Yeah I saw - edited the question.

Comment: With XSLT 1.0 you can store results in a variable and then you need to use an extension function like `exsl:node-set` to convert it to a node-set so that you can use XPath to select (or in your case count) nodes. Which XSLT processor do you use? Most support `exsl:node-set`, some Microsoft processors like MSXML support a similar function but in a Microsoft specific namespace.

Comment: @MartinHonnen The Microsoft processor also supports `exsl:node-set` in addition to the MS-specific `msxsl:node-set`.

Comment: I'm not sure which processor I'm using, but the transformation is invoked by C# code, so it would make sense it's the Microsoft processor.

Comment: Please show the definition of the function `func:Conflicts()`- otherwise nobody can run your current stylesheet. Also, there must be a namespace declaration for the `func:` prefix and your stylesheet is not well-formed because several output elements are not closed properly.

Comment: @JLRishe, there is nothing like "the Microsoft processor", there are various versions of the COM based `MSXML` and in .NET there are `XslTransform` and `XslCompiledTransform`. Of those only `XslCompiledTransform` supports `exsl:node-set`, `XslTransform` does not. And neither do the various MSXML versions, although using script you can add support for `exsl:node-set`.

Comment: Two alternative approaches to exslt:node-set(): (a) use an XSLT 2.0 processor (which makes everything so much easier!), and (b) write a pipeline containing two transformations, where the second is applied to the output of the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Martin Honnen points out, you can use a `node-set()` function to access nodes that were generated in your XSLT.

You need to declare the EXSL namespace:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
```

Capture the output in a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="overviewCollection">
  <OverviewCollection>
    <!--Iterate all iteration responses-->
    <xsl:for-each select="//IterationResponse">
      ...
    </xsl:for-each>
  </OverviewCollection>
</xsl:variable>
```

Output it:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$overviewCollection" />
```

And use the variable as needed:

```
<OverviewIndicator>
  <xsl:value-of 
      select="boolean(exsl:node-set($overviewCollection)//OverviewElement)"/>
</OverviewIndicator>
```

Here's what it looks like all put together:

```
<Overview>
  <xsl:variable name="overviewCollection">
    <OverviewCollection>
      <!--Iterate all iteration responses-->
      <xsl:for-each select="//IterationResponse">
        ...
      </xsl:for-each>
    </OverviewCollection>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:copy-of select="$overviewCollection" />
  <OverviewIndicator>
    <xsl:value-of 
        select="boolean(exsl:node-set($overviewCollection)//OverviewElement)"/>
  </OverviewIndicator>
</Overview>
```

Comment: Thanks ALOT - I've just spent half an hour adapting the transformation, using this approach and it works perfectly. Thanks - would have taken me hours, if not days to find this solution!